# How to set Sprint Boot Camel logging level?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, logback

How can I set logging level with SpringBoot 2 and camel routes? Is it possible from `application.yml`?

```
from(..).log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "${headers}${body}")
```

Below doesn't work

**application.yml**

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%-5p [%d{ISO8601}] [Thread: %t] [%X] %-55c  %m%n"
  level:
    org.apache.camel: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1):

For changing logging, you can use the below properties in application.yml.

Make sure your indentions are correct.

You have to set **your.package.name : DEBUG** - the custom log lines you write are in classes in **your.package.name** Those custom .log() are not  in 'org.apache.camel'

[image]

Sample TRACE output from the above config

[image]

Comment: If logging root: DEBUG is set then I see the .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,"") messages but it does not show with org.apache.camel: DEBUG. I do see other debug lines for camel but no .log(..)

Comment: you've to set your.package.name : DEBUG - the lines you write are in classes in your.package.name. Those custom .log() are not  in 'org.apache.camel'

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the logName or logger. Define the log level for your base package in application.yml [Log EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/log-eip.html)

```
private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchRequestRoute.class);
from(..).log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, logger, ${headers}${body}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue putting as org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger as logName

```
 <log loggingLevel="DEBUG" logName="org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger"
                     message="MESSAGE"/>
```